How can I change the font color of a key in a magit transient popup?
I am using the selenized light theme and can hardly read the keys in a transient buffer in magit, for example when I commit, because it's a faint light color on a light background.
I could not find any magit-* faces that would affect the popup buffer.
How can I make the keys more visible?


After some digging, I realized that magit uses the transient library for popup buffers. It's  by the same author behind magit.
I then used M-x helm-colors and entered transient- until I found the faces that needed to be updated. One can use the customize faces to store the modifications directly into .emacs or .spacemacs. But for easier handling, I added these lines to my .spacemacs:
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
...
  (setq theming-modifications
        '((solarized-selenized-light

           (transient-key-exit :foreground "#d2212d" :weight bold)
           (transient-key-return :foreground "#c49700" :weight bold)
           (transient-key-stay :foreground "#009c8f" :weight bold)
           )))

  (spacemacs/load-theme 'solarized-selenized-light :disable t)


You can accept your own answer.

@tarsius Thanks for checking, and more so  for all your work on Magit. I still have those stickers from your campaign a few years ago, they are amazingly durable
